flex-direction:column; working differently in chrome and firefox


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bigContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 60);
}

.smallContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  align-items: center;
  right: 0;
}

.profile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 45%;
}

.meow {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

.bio {
  /* margin-top: 2px; */
  font-weight: 700;
  /* margin-bottom: 2px; */
}

.foto {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.details {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: justify;
}
<div class="bigContainer">
<div class="smallContainer">
    <div class="profile">
        <img src="https://robohash.org/test" class="foto" />
        <span class="meow">Meow Meow Meow</span>
        <p class="bio">Meow Meow Meow Meow Meow Meow</p>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam,
            doloremque aperiam itaque officia error expedita cupiditate
            excepturi laboriosam labore veniam sit, minima ullam porro repellat
            ducimus possimus obcaecati tenetur voluptatem.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



when I open this in firefox everything seems fine works normal but opening this in chrome or in opera gx the details div is overlaping with profile div the image size is different than firefox. I tried setting margin top to separate them but then it looks weird in firefox with toomuch space in the middle.
Am I doing something wrong or is it something that needs to be handled differently across browsers?

I suspect the width on the .smallContainer is the culprit here...

Removing the position: absolute makes it work properly, also to show the content on the right side, I've added justify-content: end to the parent container.
This is how it looks now:


body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

.bigContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 60);
}

.smallContainer {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  align-items: center;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.profile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.meow {
  font-size: larger;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding: 10px;
}

.bio {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.foto {
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.details {
  width: 85%;
  text-align: justify;
}
<div class="bigContainer">
  <div class="smallContainer">
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="https://robohash.org/test" class="foto" alt="Profile Picture">
      <span class="meow">Meow Meow Meow</span>
      <p class="bio">Meow Meow Meow Meow Meow Meow</p>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam, doloremque aperiam itaque officia error expedita cupiditate exceptuofficialriosam labore veniam sit, minima ullam porro repellat ducimus possimus obcaecati tenetur voluptatem.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks it worked but why does it behave differently on chrome while using absolute. If you can please explain it to me

There are multiple reasons as to why position absolute acts this way w.r.t. the browser. Both Chrome and Firefox have different styling properties and components. You can also notice that there is a slight difference in the scrollbar width which can also be a factor.

this works but the height of big container isn't full height when setting the height to 100% does nothing and setting it to 100vh gives the same problem

try adding height: 100%; to the body.

i did, it didnt work either

I've edited my answer, check if that works out

the details div is wayyy in the bottom
